# sudo apt-get update shows unwanted sublime-text line every time

Tags: command-line, 18.04, updates, lubuntu, sublime-text

In Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, every time I run `sudo apt-get update` on the command line, there is a line displaying `Hit:4 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease`.

```
shekhar@shekhar-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease                                                                    
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                   
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                   
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Fetched 163 kB in 4s (43.0 kB/s)                                   
Reading package lists... Done
```

I tried to install sublime-text and later deleted it because it required a license key.

Now when I run sudo apt-get upgrade, following is the result:-

```
shekhar@shekhar-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you go into Preferences/Software & Updates, Other Software tab, and uncheck the box by this ppa? This may not be why you can't update the kernel though,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Removing sublime from `apt-get update`

The first one is showing sublime ppas on `apt-get update`, if you wish to get rid of it—you have to remove the ppa.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

Assuming you followed the steps from [sublime official download manual](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt), then above command should suffice for only removing the ppa.

#### kernel `have been kept back`

Since kernel are core system packages and can seriously damage your system if the upgrade fails, this cannot be done with just `upgrade`, one should issue `dist-upgrade` to upgrade these kind of packages.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This would effectively upgrade the kernel packages.